# Issue with zone.js and non angular dom element events

Tags: angular, dom, zone.js

I'm facing an issue with Zone.js and non-angular DOM element events.

This happens when we assign a javascript function to any DOM element in the HTML mark up and then programmatically re-assign the same DOM element some other or the same function.

e.g.  You have this mark up

```
<button id="button1" onclick="test1()">button 1</button>
```

and then somewhere in JS you re-assign button1 onclick with some other function

```
 document.getElementById('button1').onclick = test3;
```

In such scenarios,  two function calls are made. First one is original assigned method and then the second one is the newly assigned method.

I’ve created a PLUNKER to demo this behavior.

In the example, we have an angular app and 2 non angular buttons on the screen.   Each button is initially assigned a function which just prints some text to console.

One button (Button 1 on the onclick event ) just prints  **test 1 method called.**

The other button (Button 2  on the onclick event) prints **test 2 method called.**  And also assigns onclick of button1 a new function. This new function prints **test 3 method called.**

The scenario-

Let the application load. When you can see **App works**  do the following:-
1.  Open the debugger console.
2.  Click button 2
3.  Check the console
4.  Click button 1.
5.  Check the console.

The expectation.
•   On click on Button 2 , we should see **test 2 method called.**
•   On click on Button 1 , we should see **test 3 method called.**

The actual
•   On click on Button 2, we see **test 2 method called.**
•   On click on Button 1, we see **test 1 method called.**  Followed by **test 3

 method called.**

The PLUNKER link

https://plnkr.co/edit/ymKcHjWPrDiG73NfWBle?p=preview

On debugging , I see that one method is called DOM element event (test1 from onclick) and the other method (test3) is called by zonejs
(To this debugging, I had added console.log in zone.js file on my local machine)

I see that zonejs registers with allmost all events related to any DOM element on the screen.

So, is this an issue I'm facing ? or is it the expected behavior or am I going wrong some where? Please help with some info / pointers.

Comment: The Plunker doesn't seem to do anything. Might be a (temporary) Plunker issue though.

Comment: zone.js only affects event bindings that are made from within a zone. Angular runs within such a zone. If you do it outside, zone is not involved.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, `NgZone` is not involved. But the root zone still listens to all events

Comment: @Maximus Why would it do that? Is that something new?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I meant it patches and intercepts all async events. It's not related to Angular

Comment: @Maximus it does that for code that runs inside a zone only, at least AFAIK.

Comment: I'll try to show it on plunker, but did you'll see that console prints log of previous as well as the currently assigned onclick function? How would one explain that?  Its very confusing. Even I feel that zone shouldnt be involved... but my debugging says that , one of the method called is a wrapFn (the wrapper function) zone creates over all its events...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ceW3e1BsjbHRDPQhvDH?p=preview). I haven't created a child zone. Only the root zone is available and it listens for everything

Comment: @BhavikShah, make a plunker, without it it's impossible to debug

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/jcAxzmivK7h2RBx7fA2b?p=preview

try this one @Maximus . See if it helps.. in the console you'll see zone getting called...

Comment: root zone listening to every event isn't a problem, but its triggering extra events..  (I don't know if thats the expected behaviour though)

Comment: @BhavikShah, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197095/2545680), it'll explain what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that zone patches `onclick` and uses `addEventListener/removeEventListener` to register/remove a callback for the button. But the `onclick` registers its own independent handler that can't be removed with `removeEventListener`. So effectively you end up with two handlers for the `click` event:

```
function patchProperty(obj, prop, prototype) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
    ...
    desc.set = function (newValue) {
        ...
        var previousValue = target[_prop];
        if (previousValue) {
            // !!!!!! ------------------ it doesn't remove onclick here ---------- !!!!!!
            target.removeEventListener(eventName, previousValue); 
        }
        if (typeof newValue === 'function') {
            var wrapFn = function (event) {
              console.log(' zone wrap function called for--\n');
              console.log('targetID '+target.id);
              console.log('event is '+eventName);
                var result = newValue.apply(this, arguments);
                if (result != undefined && !result) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                return result;
            };
            target[_prop] = wrapFn;

            // !!!!!! ------------------ but adds new handler here ---------- !!!!!!
            target.addEventListener(eventName, wrapFn, false);
```

This situation can be easily reproduced without zones:

```
    function onClickHandler() {
        console.log('onClickHandler');
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.removeEventListener('click', button.onclick);
        button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
            console.log('addEventListener')
        });
    });

   <button onclick="onClickHandler()">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Yes..Got it. Thanks :) and so it correct to say that zone.js has an issue ??

Comment: It's hard to tell. On the surface, yes, it does seems that `zone.js` doesn't remove handler correctly, but I don't know there thinking. Create a github issue and we will see. If you do, please put a reference here.

Comment: well, we went on checking the zone.js code and the code itself has a reference to the issue.

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/525

Comment: I added it to my previous comment . Here, again, 

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/525

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149725/discussion-between-bhavik-shah-and-maximus).

Comment: what do you want to talk about?

Answer (score 2):

One of the resolution is to patch "desc.set" method of zone.js to resolve this issue.

```
function patchProperty(obj, prop, prototype) {
var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
...
desc.set = function (newValue) {
...
var previousValue = target[_prop];
if (previousValue) {
    target.removeEventListener(eventName, previousValue);
}//Start Fix
else{ 
    if(originalDescGet){
         if (typeof target['removeAttribute'] === 'function') {
             target.removeAttribute(prop);
         }
    }   
}//End fix
```

Comment: This solution seems to work. Thanks :) I'll update the GitHub with this issue and put the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Not angular but zonejs is causing this behavior. Working with some trial error.

https://plnkr.co/edit/cnDy4utsWYbhaXIBluNw?p=preview

1. Moved inline events listeners to `window.onload`
2. updated `test2()` method to remove and add listener for button1

Comment: yup.. in my question's comment we had the same discussion.  So in legacy systems, this creates an issue...  have u faced such issues?  how to overcome them?